# How can I pass command line arguments containing braces using sun grid engine qsub?

Tags: python, sungridengine

I have a Python script that I would like to run on sun grid engine, and this script accepts a string command line argument that might contain braces. For instance, the script could be `script.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

If I run `python script.py aaa{` the output is `aaa{`, and if I run `python script.py aaa{}` the output is `aaa{}`. These are both the desired behavior.

However, if I run `qsub -b y -cwd python script.py aaa{` the job fails with error `Missing }.`, and if I run `qsub -b y -cwd python script.py aaa{}` the job succeeds but outputs `aaa`. This is not the desired behavior.

My hypothesis is that qsub does some preprocessing of the command line arguments to my script, but I don't want it to do this. Is there any way to make qsub pass command line arguments to my script as is, regardless of whether they contain braces or not?

Comment: Does `qsub -b y -cwd python -- script.py  AAA{` work?

Comment: No. Adding `--` there does not appear to change the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by running `qsub -b y -cwd -shell no python script.py aaa{}` instead of `qsub -b y -cwd python script.py aaa{}`. On my system, `-shell yes` seemed to be enabled by default, which initiated some preprocessing. Adding `-shell no` appears to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use

```
echo "python script.py aaa{}" | qsub -cwd
```

You could also create submit file containing the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd

python ./script.py ${input}
```

Then, you can pass your input via `qsub -v input=aaa{} script.submit`

Both variants require to omit `-b y`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but these solutions do not work for me. In both cases the output is `aaa` instead of the desired `aaa{}`. Additionally, I have been using `-b y` because `python` is a binary.

Comment: This is interesting, I tested both variants on two different SGE installations. Do you get an error? Or the brackets are just not printed?

Comment: If my argument is `aaa{}` no error comes up and the output is `aaa` - the braces are just not printed. If my argument is `aaa{` there is an error `Missing }.` and no output.